# TableView Visible cell count is same in iPhone5, iPhone6 & iPhone6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone

In my application I have a `UITableView` whose cell height is **200**(fixed). When I run this Application in iPhone5 simulator(4 inch, screen-height 1136) it shows me almost 2 cell in the screen. This is pretty okay.Screen shot is here

[image]

When I run this app in iPhone6 simulator(4.7 inch, screen height 1334) it shows me the same 2 cell and also in iPhone6 Plus simulator(5.5 inch, screen height 1920) it shows 2 cells only. Logically as iPhone6 have bigger screen size so it should show me 2 and half cell or more and iPhone6 Plus should show 3 and half cell or more (at least not 2 cells as in iPhone5)

Here is the screen shot of iPhone6 Simulator:

[image]

And iPhone6 Plus Simulator:

[image]

Why it shows same in the new iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus? and how to fix this?